# Distributed pg_dump job using Apache Spark

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

**Hello everyone!**
I'm using pg_dump to create a dump of my database and save it to S3.
I manage multiple postgresql databases with different sizes, some of them small and others big and have a lot of data.
My problem is that the pg_dump command takes too long on large databases. I thought about distributing the load of the command with the use of Apache Spark capabilities.

**This brings up 2 questions on my side:**

1. Is it possible to use Apache Spark in order to run a distributed pg_dump job?
2. If so how will it be executed?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't distribute a postgresql command like this with spark.

The easiest way to save postgresql data into S3 using spark is to use the spark api.

pseudo code:

```
foreach table:
sparksession
  .read()
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database" , table)
  .write("s3://save/directory")
```

more info:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html